# Using minified script.js and it's source map .js.map to recover the original source code

Tags: javascript, webpack, minify, source-maps, js-beautify

So am trying to get a readable code from a minimified js script and it's source map , i would like to know if it's possible to do that using just these two entry and how .
Thanks for helping

Comment: A source map without the corresponding source is like a long list of references to the *nth word on the mth row on page x* of a book you don't have.

Comment: thanks for replying , so even with the minimified code and it's source map i can't get the original code , is there any tips for debugging the script otherwise ?